# typescript errors on union type when accessing object properties

Tags: typescript

I'm confused why the following gives errors in my IDE:

I have some interfaces/types

**interfaces/types:**

```
interface GradientColor {
  type: string;
  value: {
    angle: string | number;
    colours: string[];
  };
}

interface NormalColor {
  type: string;
  value: string;
}

type ColorOptions = GradientColor | NormalColor;
```

(mix of UK and US spellings here)

**usage:**

so I would now like to use these in a function

```
const parseCSSColor = (color: ColorOptions) => {
  // ...
  return `linear-gradient(${color.value.angle}deg, ${color.value.colors[0]}, ${color.value.colors[1]})`;
  // ...
}
```

**issue:**

so now thats all set up, my IDE says:

```
Property 'angle' does not exist on type 'string | { angle: string | number; colours: string[]; }'.
  Property 'angle' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

why? `color.value` should be able to be a string or an object with `.angle` and `.colours`

Comment: You have to type narrow to assert that those properties do exist

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: ah wait i looked into it a bit more and know what you mean now, thank you!

Comment: It appears you think that a variable (`color`) declared to be of a union type may be used with the properties of either type (`GradientColor` and `NormalColor`), 
which is a possible interpretation of the concept of union, but it is not so in typescript - it actually means that the variable has only the common properties 
of the two types - *"TypeScript will only allow an operation if it is valid for every member of the union"*
as per the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types)
which also explains narrowing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types) the type of `color` to let Typescript know if it's a `GradientColor` or a `NormalColor`.

```
const parseCSSColor = (color: ColorOptions) => {
  if (typeof color.value === "string") {
    // Typescript now sees color as an instance of NormalColor
  } else {
    // Typescript now sees color as an instance of GradientColor
    return `linear-gradient(${color.value.angle}deg, ${color.value.colors[0]}, ${color.value.colors[1]})`;
  }
}
```

You'll also want to check in the else clause if the length of `colours: string[]` is at least 2 or change its type to a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)  if you want to access the first two elements without a Typescript error.